# how to display 3 ,3 item in listview when we pull to refresh in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private List<String> mListItems;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.expertscommentsListView))
        .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Do work to refresh the list here.
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }
        });

mListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);
final PullToRefreshListView listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.expertscommentsListView);
//setListAdapter(adapter);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);   
   }




    private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Simulates a background job.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            return mStrings;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            mListItems.add(0, "Added new item after refresh...");
            // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
            ((PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.expertscommentsListView)).onRefreshComplete();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    private String[] mStrings = { "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
            "Andhra Pradesh", "Arunachal Pradesh", "Assam", "Bihar",
            "Chhattisgarh", "Goa", "Gujarat", "Haryana", "Himachal Pradesh",
            "Jammu and Kashmir", "Jharkhand", "Karnataka", "Kerala",
            "Madhya Pradesh", "Maharashtra", "Manipur" };


}
```

This is my Code i want to display listview 3 item first when i do pull to refresh then again 3 item should load and again if we pull to refresh then it should display 3 more item currently i am adding some new item when i pull to refresh in android please help me how to display 3 to 3 item load pull to refresh in android

Comment: found solution for problem ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no please help me

Answer (score 0):

To update ListView on pull to refresh event you first need to divide Array with size of 3.then in `onRefresh()` call `onRefreshComplete()`  to complete . do it as:

**1.** Divide Array in parts with the size of 3:

```
int partitionSize = 3; 
ArrayList<String> arrQuestionCount = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(mStrings));
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partition = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
 for (int i = 0; i < arrQuestionCount.size(); i += partitionSize) {
     List<String> list = arrQuestionCount.subList(i,
             i + Math.min(partitionSize, arrQuestionCount.size() - i));
     partition.add(new ArrayList<String>(list)); 
 }
```

**2.** Pass initial size to ListView `setTag` method for next use:

```
  listView.setTag(0);
```

**3.** Add `setOnRefreshListener` to ListView:

```
listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Do work to refresh the list here.
                int index=Integer.parseInt(listView.getTag());
                if(index <partition.size()){
                  new GetDataTask().execute(index);
                  listView.setTag(index++);
                }
            }
        });
```

**4.** In `doInBackground` get index and return `ArrayList` from partition:

```
 @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        return partition[params[0]];
    }
```

**5.** Add new data in Adapter using `Adapter.addAll` :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
    mListItems.add(0, "Added new item after refresh..."); 
    adapter.addAll(result);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
        public void run() {
          listView.onRefreshComplete();
        }
    }, 200); 
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Comment: partition  we have to intilize this @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @Edge: jsut create ArrayList as `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partition = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();`

Comment: The method execute(Void...) in the type AsyncTask<Void,Void,String[]> is not applicable for the arguments (int)  this Error is coming onPost Excute @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @Edge: change `AsyncTask<Integer,Void,ArrayList<String>>` to `AsyncTask<Void,Void,String[]>`

Comment: can u make it aSynk task coz     return partition[params[arg0]]; here error is coming  @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: return partition[params[arg0]]; params cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @Edge: use `doInBackground(Integer... params)` instead of `doInBackground(Void... params)`

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/6xyHp6Q55XbQjjdWPHB9rz this code i have tried for Asynk task but still same Error is coming

Comment: @Edge: your `return partition.get(arg0[0]);`  instead of `return partition[params[arg0]];`

Comment: after pull to refresh this exception coming http://paste.ofcode.org/ACvjg7RPgXbTYHKDA5ggr4

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/3ERntBFBPjhw738KLrR9XC here is my complte code @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K can i have ur email id so that will do and replay u

Comment: still same issue return partition.get(0); please tell me how to fix cani show u full code

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K u there ?